# Need assistance with SQL query for data extract

Tags: sql, unique

The SQL query I have written retrieved 3677 rows where the `cutomerID` field contains many duplicate data . I want to write query which will give me all the below required fields with unique `cutomerID` only. We can't use distinct for `customerID` only as other fields are of different data type. Please assist me with this query:

```
  SELECT TimeMark,
        CustomerID,
        AccountId,
        TargetURL
    FROM BTILog
    WHERE timemark BETWEEN '20140926 00:00:00'
            AND '20141020 23:59:59'
        AND TargetURL LIKE '%/api/v1/cust/details%'
        AND Class LIKE 'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%'
    ORDER BY TimeMark DESC
```

[image: Please have a look the data I am getting from the below query. There you can see duplicate customerID as highlighted in blue line. I want the 57155299 customer only once with last time mark, similarly if there will be any other customer who have appeared twice/thrice or so on, theey should only once in my data extract]

Comment: Do you need just a single record per customer? Or do you need them grouped by customer. If you can't use distinct, it's because the records as a whole aren't distinct, and naturally that gives you different results. If that data is irrelevant please clarify with more details.

Comment: I need distinct customer record as a whole with all the four fields. grouping by customer will be okay. I didn't have the reputation of 10 else i will send the image of what currently I don't want. please let em know if you require more clarification.

Comment: Techinically speaking the rows you highlighted are not the same row, so using distinct won't work because  `TimeMark` throws it off. In order to "combine" those rows into one, you have to exclude `TimeMark` from the Query, or pull `MAx(TimeMark)` so they can be combined

Comment: What RDBMS are you using (MySQL, Oracle, SQL-Server)? The answers are using implementation-dependent features like `RANK`, so please tag your question more specifically so that appropriate answers can be written.

Comment: When there are duplicate rows with the same CustomerID _which one do you want?_ Do you want the oldest? newest? A count of how many there were? The SQL here will not be difficult, once you decide how to disambiguate the answer.

Comment: Hi Guys... The RDBMS  I am using is SQL Server. And replying to Andrew... I want the count of duplicate cutomersID and their details as well who are appered more than once in my records. Let me know in case any query.

Answer (score 1):

You should use group by and aggregating function on TimeMark.
The following will give you unique Customer ID records with the last entry time mark for each:

```
SELECT max(TimeMark) TimeMark,
        CustomerID,
        AccountId,
        TargetURL
    FROM BTILog
    WHERE timemark BETWEEN '20140926 00:00:00'
            AND '20141020 23:59:59'
        AND TargetURL LIKE '%/api/v1/cust/details%'
        AND Class LIKE 'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%'
    GROUP BY CustomerID, AccountId,TargetURL
    ORDER BY TimeMark DESC
```

Comment: This should work for you assuming you are only interested in the most recent time_mark.  IF you want the earliest, you could, of course use Min(TimeMark).  This does assume that there is exactly one AccountId per Customer.  Otherwise you may still have duplicates.  It also assumes you will not have multiple Classes that match your LIKE condition.

Answer (score 0):

I believe ranking your result will give you your desired result. Similar to this.

```
select TimeMark,
        CustomerID,
        AccountId,
        TargetURL
    from (
        select TimeMark,
            CustomerID,
            AccountId,
            TargetURL,
            rank() over (
                CustomerID order by TimeMark desc
                ) rank_
        from BTILog
        where timemark between '20140926 00:00:00'
                and '20141020 23:59:59'
            and TargetURL like '%/api/v1/cust/details%'
            and Class like 'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%'
        )
    where rank_ = 1;
```

You could also include AccountId in your partitioning clause if that's your desired result.

```
rank() over (
                    CustomerID, AccountId order by TimeMark desc
                    ) rank_
```

Also if there are rows that have the same CustomerID, AccountId  and TimeMark you could use row_number instead of rank. Which will arbitrarily assign a greater rank to one of the tied rows.

Comment: Thanks Will. I haven't used rank function before but will surely try this and will google more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select distinct CustomerId, AccountId, TargetURL,
                Max(TimeMark) over (partition by CustomerId) as 'MaxTM'
  FROM BTILog
    WHERE timemark BETWEEN '20140926 00:00:00'
            AND '20141020 23:59:59'
        AND TargetURL LIKE '%/api/v1/cust/details%'
        AND Class LIKE 'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%'
   group by CustomerId, AcconutId, TargetUrl --I don't think this is needed
    ORDER BY MaxTM DESC
```

Comment: @C Sharper : Thank you mate. I will surely try and will come back.

Comment: @C : Hi executing your query i got the following error: 'BTILog.TimeMark is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. ORDER BY clause must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: I think the problem is, that we are not giving a name to the column where we are doing the partitionion by, and then trying to order by that very column. See my edit. Because `Max(TimeMark) over (partition by CustomerId) <> TimeMark` which was in our order by

Comment: @C : thanks Sharper, your query is working fine. I just added TimeMark in the group by clause to avoid the error earlier pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

Every field selected must either be part of the group by or aggregated (as with MAX, SUM, COUNT, etc.)  Looks like in your case you have to group on CustomerID, AccountId, and possibly TargetURL (if they are all the same, group by; if not, perhaps MAX(TargetURL)) and figure out what you want to do with TimeMark -- MAX(TimeMark) perhaps?

You might try one of the following, depending on the nature of TargetURL:

```
SELECT MAX(TimeMark), CustomerID, AccountId, TargetURL
FROM BTILog
WHERE timemark BETWEEN '20140926 00:00:00'
    AND '20141020 23:59:59'
    AND TargetURL LIKE '%/api/v1/cust/details%'
    AND Class LIKE 'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%'
CustomerID, AccountId, TargetURL
ORDER BY TimeMark DESC
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(TimeMark), CustomerID, AccountId, MAX(TargetURL)
FROM BTILog
WHERE timemark BETWEEN '20140926 00:00:00'
    AND '20141020 23:59:59'
    AND TargetURL LIKE '%/api/v1/cust/details%'
    AND Class LIKE 'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%'
GROUP BY CustomerID, AccountId
ORDER BY TimeMark DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a subquery , to return the record with the max TimeMark, based on the criteria, then join on CustomerID and TimeMark, this will limit the result to the record you want

```
SELECT BTILog.TimeMark, BTILog.CustomerID, BTILog.AccountID, BTILog.TargetUrl
FROM BTILog
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Max(BTILog.TimeMark) AS MaxOfTimeMark, BTILog.CustomerID
  FROM BTILog
  WHERE (((BTILog.TargetUrl) Like '%/api/v1/cust/details%')
    AND ((BTILog.Class) Like  'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%')
    AND ((BTILog.TimeMark) BETWEEN '20140926 00:00:00' AND '20141020 23:59:59'))
  GROUP BY BTILog.CustomerID) AS T1
ON (BTILog.CustomerID = T1.CustomerID)
  AND (BTILog.TimeMark = T1.MaxOfTimeMark)
ORDER by BTILog.TimeMark DESC
```

I generally work in the MS Access query editor so the syntax differs, I think I changed anything that may cause it to "fall over"

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data and considering your query is correct then.

```
Select * from 
(SELECT TimeMark,
        CustomerID,
        AccountId,
        TargetURL,
        **ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by CustomerID order by TimeMark desc)rownum**
    FROM BTILog
    WHERE timemark BETWEEN '20140926 00:00:00'
            AND '20141020 23:59:59'
        AND TargetURL LIKE '%/api/v1/cust/details%'
        AND Class LIKE 'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%'
    ORDER BY TimeMark DESC
    ) tbl where rownum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `rank` function or the `rownum` tricks would help, since you're not dealing with a sorted list of the same unique keys, but for each `CustomerID, A.AccountId` you're looking for the record that is within the specified period of time that has the max time mark

You can try this:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
        A.BTimeMark,
        A.CustomerID,
        A.AccountId,
        A.TargetURL
    FROM BTILog A
    WHERE A.timemark =
    (
          SELECT MAX(B.TimeMark)
          FROM BTILog B
          WHERE B.timemark BETWEEN '20140926 00:00:00' AND '20141020 23:59:59'
            AND B.TargetURL LIKE '%/api/v1/cust/details%'
            AND B.Class LIKE 'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%'

            AND B.CustomerID = A.CustomerID
            AND B.AccountId = A.AccountId
    )
    AND A.TargetURL LIKE '%/api/v1/cust/details%'
    AND A.Class LIKE 'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%'
    ORDER BY A.TimeMark DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

in sql server i use for the date  >= Convert(nchar(10),first_date_value,103)............

Answer (score 0):

What about a subselect, which counts the rows for the current customerid

```
  SELECT TimeMark,
        CustomerID,
        AccountId,
        TargetURL
    FROM BTILog ALIAS outer
    WHERE timemark BETWEEN '20140926 00:00:00'
            AND '20141020 23:59:59'
        AND TargetURL LIKE '%/api/v1/cust/details%'
        AND Class LIKE 'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%'
        AND (
                SELECT count(*) 
                FROM BTILog
                WHERE timemark BETWEEN '20140926 00:00:00'
                AND '20141020 23:59:59'
                AND TargetURL LIKE '%/api/v1/cust/details%'
                AND Class LIKE 'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%'
                AND outer.CustomerID = CustomerID
        ) == 1

    ORDER BY TimeMark DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

Use group by CustomerID and also had in a duplicate column so you can keep track of how many duplicates are there. You don't need the TimeMark then because they will be duplicate Times

```
SELECT TimeMark,
        CustomerID,
        COUNT(CustomerID) AS duplicate,
        AccountId,
        TargetURL
    FROM BTILog
    WHERE timemark BETWEEN '20140926 00:00:00'
            AND '20141020 23:59:59'
        AND TargetURL LIKE '%/api/v1/cust/details%'
        AND Class LIKE 'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%'
   GROUP BY(CustomerID)
    ORDER BY TimeMark DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Edward, it looked more convincing.

Comment: sorry for getting back to you so late. but executing our query returned the below error - Msg 8120,Level16,State1, Line2  Column 'BTILog.TimeMark is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

You could write a subquery to select DISTINCT from only the CustomerID.

```
 SELECT TimeMark, 
        (SELECT DISTINCT CustomerID 
        FROM BTILog
        WHERE timemark BETWEEN '20140926 00:00:00'
            AND '20141020 23:59:59'
        AND TargetURL LIKE '%/api/v1/cust/details%'
        AND Class LIKE 'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%') 
        AS CustyID, 
        AccountId,
        TargetURL
    FROM BTILog
    WHERE timemark BETWEEN '20140926 00:00:00'
            AND '20141020 23:59:59'
        AND TargetURL LIKE '%/api/v1/cust/details%'
        AND Class LIKE 'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%'
    ORDER BY TimeMark DESC
```

Comment: Using your query i got the following error: 
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score -1):

You in all probability need to re-design your data structure to split the data into two tables, one defining Customer and the other acting as a time stamp. Each customer record will be unique, with or without the use of DISTINCT. The Time Stamp table will link to the Customer Table via a Foreign Key, a similar CustomerID field and the Timestamp, together with any other fields that you need to record at each periodic event. Schematically:

Customer:
CustomerID, Integer, Unique.
AccountID, Integer.
TargetURL, Text 250.

TimeStamp:
TimeID, Integer, Unique.
TimeMark, DateTime.
CustomerID, Integer

The CustomerID from Customers and TimeID from TimeStamp should probably be AutoIncrement 'Crash Number' fields. The CustomerID fields in each Table act as the link. With this, rationalised schemata your queries will start to fall into place easily and you will be able to extract the data you need without sophistications like DISTINCT and UNIQUE ROWS.

Answer (score -1):

You should group by `CustomerID` and get the records `HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) = 1`; That should give you all the records where CustomerID is unique

```
SELECT TimeMark,
    CustomerID,
    AccountId,
    TargetURL
FROM BTILog
WHERE timemark BETWEEN '20140926 00:00:00'
        AND '20141020 23:59:59'
    AND TargetURL LIKE '%/api/v1/cust/details%'
    AND Class LIKE 'com.btfin.security.sso.SSODetailsFactory%'
ORDER BY TimeMark DESC
GROUP BY CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(CustomerID) = 1;
```